# presentViewController transparent background doesn't work on iPad 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, retina

I try to open a popup with a transparent background so that we can see the screen behind the popup.
I use this code :

```
- (void)presentErrorMessageVC:(NSString *)message {

// Get error message vc
S6ErrorMessageVC *vc = [[S6ErrorMessageVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"S6ErrorMessageVC" bundle:nil message:message];

if (vc) {
    // Set delegate
    vc.delegate = self;

    // Present error message vc
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
}
```

Which works perfectly, except for ipad 4, where the background is black. I've also tried to add

```
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But still the background is black...
Any idea?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

This may help you solve your problem.

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Comment: Nope, nothing change :(